# Deployed a react native app in iphone using xcode but app not working

Tags: ios, react-native

Deployed a react native app on iphone but whenever I try to open the app it shows the name of the app and after few seconds app closes by itself.
While when I run the same app on my ios emulator it works like charm.
What could be the problem?
Thanks in advance

log :

```
Date/Time:           2018-09-27 17:01:44.8982 +0530
Launch Time:         2018-09-27 17:01:24.8192 +0530
OS Version:          iPhone OS 12.0 (16A366)
Baseband Version:    5.10.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, scene-create watchdog transgression: com.ccmtTweets.Tweets1234 exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 19.95 seconds | ProcessVisibility: Foreground | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: scene-create | WatchdogVisibility: Foreground | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 2.520 (user 2.520, system 0.000), 6% CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.085, 0% CPU" | )
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000224515f0c semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000224364fc4 _dispatch_sema4_wait$VARIANT$mp + 24
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000224365a48 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 136
3   CFNetwork                       0x0000000224fdace8 CFURLConnectionSendSynchronousRequest + 292
4   CFNetwork                       0x0000000224f3788c +[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:] + 116
5   ccmtTweetApp                    0x0000000104dbec44 -[RCTBundleURLProvider isPackagerRunning:] + 1223748 (RCTBundleURLProvider.m:74)
6   ccmtTweetApp                    0x0000000104dbeef4 -[RCTBundleURLProvider guessPackagerHost] + 1224436 (RCTBundleURLProvider.m:90)
7   ccmtTweetApp                    0x0000000104dbf104 -[RCTBundleURLProvider packagerServerHost] + 1224964 (RCTBundleURLProvider.m:104)
8   ccmtTweetApp                    0x0000000104dbf1f8 -[RCTBundleURLProvider jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:fallbackResource:fallbackExtension:] + 1225208 (RCTBundleURLProvider.m:114)
9   ccmtTweetApp                    0x0000000104dbf398 -[RCTBundleURLProvider jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:fallbackResource:] + 1225624 (RCTBundleURLProvider.m:127)
10  ccmtTweetApp                    0x0000000104c9a0ac -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 24748 (AppDelegate.m:19)
11  UIKitCore                       0x00000002512065f8 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 412
12  UIKitCore                       0x0000000251207d60 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3340
13  UIKitCore                       0x000000025120d7ac -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1552
14  UIKitCore                       0x0000000251a34db8 __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 784
15  UIKitCore                       0x0000000251a31364 +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 160
16  UIKitCore                       0x0000000251a34a34 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 240
17  UIKitCore                       0x0000000251a353d4 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 1076
18  UIKitCore                       0x00000002519f45fc __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 772
19  UIKitCore                       0x00000002519f42a8 -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 432
20  UIKitCore                       0x0000000251a37844 __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 220
21  UIKitCore                       0x0000000251a38334 _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 112
22  UIKitCore                       0x0000000251a376fc -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 248
23  UIKitCore                       0x0000000251a30a10 -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 368
24  UIKitCore                       0x000000025120bca4 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 540
25  UIKitCore                       0x000000025123d45c -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 364
26  FrontBoardServices              0x00000002273bb890 -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 444
27  FrontBoardServices              0x00000002273c6658 __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 260
28  FrontBoardServices              0x00000002273c5d50 __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 64
29  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000002243c4484 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
30  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000224367e58 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 224
31  FrontBoardServices              0x00000002273fa640 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 40
32  FrontBoardServices              0x00000002273fa2cc -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 416
33  FrontBoardServices              0x00000002273fa8e8 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
34  CoreFoundation                  0x000000022491a5b8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
35  CoreFoundation                  0x000000022491a538 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 88
36  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000224919e1c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 176
37  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000224914ce8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1040
38  CoreFoundation                  0x00000002249145b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
39  GraphicsServices                0x0000000226b88584 GSEventRunModal + 100
40  UIKitCore                       0x000000025120f558 UIApplicationMain + 212
41  ccmtTweetApp                    0x0000000104c9a4ec main + 25836 (main.m:14)
42  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000002243d4b94 start + 4
```

Comment: Please provide system logs

Comment: Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD